# Kubuntu18.04 stopped booting after installing a package. Only black screen

Tags: boot, package-management, crash, boot-partition

I installed Kubuntu 18.04 a few hours ago and everything was running smoothly until I installed4 the zlib1g package due to a software that renders 3d geometry. Now it doesn't boot any more but I can boot in recovery mode. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
```

and i got this error:

```
Reading packages lists…Done
Correcting dependencies…Done
The following additional packages will be installed;
  zlib1g zlib1g:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  zlib1g zlib1g:i386
2 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 178 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 115 KB of archives.
After this operation, 30.7 KB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Err:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 zlib1g amd64 1:1.2.11.dgsg-Oubuntu2
Temporary failure resolving ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err2: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 zlib1g i386 1:1.2.11.dgsg-Oubuntu2
Temporary failure resolving ‘gb.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g_1.2.11.dsfg-Oubuntu2_amd64.deb Temporary failure
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g_1.2.11.dsfg-Oubuntu2_i386.deb Temporary failure
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with—fix-missing?
```

Also tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and the same error where Linux couldn't fetch from the http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com.ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease

I checked the website myself and the link doesn't exist in fact.

Does someone have an idea why the files are not available in the above website? Or at least what to do to have Linux booting again?

Comment: `ping gb.archive.ubuntu.com` seems to work. Please raise your other issue about the partition filling up as a separate question.

Comment: The URL is this: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease

Comment: I think you need to enter sudo apt-get upgrade . Have you tried it?

Comment: The address mentioned on my first post was automatically given when i used sudo apt-get install --fix-broken. If you guys check this one: gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu for me nothing shows up. However, clicking on the link posted by @meskobalazs i can see that there is content on the page. I'm lost on this one. Any ideas? I'm focused on getting the boot to GUI back and then i'll create a new post about the partition filling up quickly. Thanks again.

Comment: after running 'sudo apt-get upgrade' i get a message saying to try 'apt --fix-broken install' which i tried and i see this as the first line W: Not using locking for read pnly lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock, more lines below with the W: in front and then i'm asked if i want to continue. I hit y and then mre error lines saying that "Failed to fecth http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib1g_1.2.11.dsfg-Oubuntu2_amd64.deb

Comment: Hi DeepSheep - how did you install zlib1g? Did you use Discover (i can't find it there) or did you use `sudo apt install` ? Were there any errors when you installed it? Did the machine run fine after the install and only when you rebooted or shutdown and restarted later did it become apparent that there was a problem?

Comment: I don't know why installing a package would cause you to boot to a black screen. *You might need to give more details about what you see before the black screen when you are booting up*. As far as your system setup goes, I think you should have a read of this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq to understand swap a little more. As far as I can tell, unless you plan on using *hibernate* you would be fine with a swap partition of about 8GB. (The swap file can be a little fiddly to set up, so a swap partition is probably more straightforward.) You'd gain a lot more useable space.

Comment: @DeepSheep - glad you got everything back up and running again! If you have a bit of time later it'd be great if you could put an answer to your question that would let other people know what fixed things for you. There's a chance that other users might have tried installing a package and ended up with a similar problem, so finding your answer might put them on the right track.

Comment: @DeepSheep - thanks for taking the time to write your answer. What I meant to say was, instead of your solution being hidden in the comments, if you answer your own question (By typing it into the 'Your Answer' box below) then it will be easier for others to see and more likely to help someone searching for a solution to find it :) You should be able to cut and paste what you've written into the 'Your Answer' section and you can also select the 'Accept this answer' part as shown here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 1):

@pHeLiOn, thanks for pointing that. I'm new to the forum so learning how to use it.

Ok, so I have found a solution for the problem. Here is what I did.

I installed Kubuntu18.04 to use a 3D software called Houdini and a render software called Redshift. After installing both with no problems (right click on packages, "Extract", then right-click on executable and "Actions/Run in Konsole"), I had to install the Redshift license through the licensing tool. To run that tool, I had to have a package installed called libpng12-0. This is where the problem started, instead of installing the 64bit version (amd64) of the package, I installed the 32bit (i386) one. By the way, here's the right link to download the amd64 version of the libpng12-0 package: packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download

From that point on, Kubuntu wasn't booting to the GUI interface. I tried removing the package by running `sudo dpkg --list` and `sudo apt-get --purge remove "package name"` and the package wouldn't uninstall. Then I tried `sudo apt-get autoclean` and also `sudo apt-get autoremove` but no succsessfull results, still not booting to the GUI.

As i'm new to Linux, I decided to re-install Kubuntu and then went over the same process to install the softwares but this time I installed the right package (libpng12-0 amd64) and since then, the machine is working very well and extremely fast! Kubuntu 18.04 is just an amazing OS to work with IMO. Thanks to the team that put it together and thanks @pHeLiOn and other users that posted the info to my question above. Much appreciatted!